# babel-preset-react-native and higher order components

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I have just updated a project from RN 53 to 56, which means that babel also has been updated from version 6 to 7, which is causing me an issue which I can't really make sense of.

It appears that classes extended inside a function retains only the class they extends, but not the extentions. The new constructor appears to be run though.

The issue seams to be caused by `babel-preset-react-native@5.0.2`

To reproduce the issue, I have tried to generate a small example where i create and return a class inside a function

```
class A {
  a() {
    return 'a';
  }
}

const createB = () => {
  class B extends A {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.c = 'c';
    }

    b() {
      return 'b';
    }
  }

  return B;
}

const CB = createB();

console.log('a: ', typeof new CB().a);
console.log('b: ', typeof new CB().b);
console.log('c: ', typeof new CB().c);
```

If i run this as `yarn babel-node --presets=react-native index.js` `new CB().b` never gets defined

```
a:  function
b:  undefined
c:  string
```

If i instead run it without preset or `@babel/preset-env` it behaves as I expect.

```
a:  function
b:  function
c:  string
```

Anyone who has experience similar problems? I can solve it by loading `react-native` and then `@babel/preset-env`, but this causes some other issues from modules which uses class properties, which means that i need `@babel/preset-env` before `react-native`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "err",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears to be working when using metro bundlers preset `yarn babel-node --presets=metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/index.js index.js`

Comment: Except when actually running in bundler then it throws `.overrides is not allowed in preset options`

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the similar issue when I upgrade to RN 56 and babel-preset-react-native 5.02, then I switched babel-preset-react-native back to 5.0.0, everything works fine.